# Proof that for any $r^3 > 2$ there exists an $h>0$ such that $(r-h)^3>2$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that for any $r^3 > 2$ there exists an $h>0$ such that $(r-h)^3>2$. I know this is true and I'm trying to prove it using only high school level algebra. So no intermediate value theorems or continuity of real numbers.
So far I have this

$$(r-h)^3=(r-h)(r^2-2rh+h^2\ )=r^3-3r^2\ h+3rh^2-h^3$$

$$r^3-\left(r-h\right)^3=3r^2h-3rh^2+h^3$$

Since $h^2>0$

$$<3r^2h+h^3$$

However, I don't know how to proceed. I know for $r$'s close to $2$ then $h<1$. But I can't find an expression that assures $h>0$ and that simplifies to at most $r^3-2$ (so as to guarantee that $r^3-\left(r-h\right)^3<r^3-2$ which implies $(r-h)^3>2$).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $0 < h < r$ is
$$
 (r-h)^3 = r^3 - 3r^2h + \underbrace{3rh^2 - h^3}_{> 0} > r^3 - 3r^2 h
$$
so that the choice
$$
 h = \frac{r^3-2}{3r^2} > 0 
$$
gives
$$
 (r-h)^3 > r^3 - 3r^2 h = 2 \, .
$$

This also happens to be one step from [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) applied to the function $f(x) = x^3 - 2$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! As an aside to those in future note that $3rh^2-h^3 > 0$ because $h^2(3r-h)>0$ since $h^2>0$ and $r>h$ means $3r-h>0$.

Answer (score 7):

$r^3 > 2\implies r>\sqrt[3]2$. Show that exists an $h>0$ such that $(r-h)^3>2$.  $(r-h)^3>2 \implies r-h > \sqrt[3] 2 \implies -h>\sqrt[3] 2 -r \implies h<r-\sqrt[3] 2  .$Note that $h>0 $ since $r>\sqrt[3]2$. Just take $0<h<r-\sqrt[3]2$. $\square$

Comment: But if $h=r-\sqrt[3]{2}$ then $(r-h)^2 = 2$... Maybe take h betwenn $0$ and $r-\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, yes any positive value less than $r-\sqrt[3]2$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I believe that yours is the simplest answer

Comment: thanks , yes I tried to show it with only high school methods. If it is fine please accept the solution. Thanks it was not super trivial to find just elementary passages to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

we are allowed to make restrictions on the variables. Since $1^3 = 1$   we know $r > 1. $  Next, as a separate case we point out that, when $r \geq 2,$  then $r^3 \geq 8,  r^3 - 2 \geq 6;$ but then $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3 - 2 = \frac{11}{8} < 6$   does better.

We continue with $1 < r < 2 .$  Note that
$$h^2 - 3hr + 3 r^2  = \left( h - \frac{3r}{2}  \right)^2  + \frac{3}{4}  r^2 \geq 0 $$   and is strictly positive  unless $h=r=0$

As $1 < r < 2$  and  we want  $ 1 < r-h <2,$   we may demand $0 < h < 1.$
With these restrictions,
$$h^2 - 3hr + 3 r^2  < h^2 + 3 r^2  < 1 + 12 = 13  $$
for any $(r,h)$

You wanted   $ r^3 - 2  >  h(h^2 - 3hr + 3 r^2).$  Just take
$$   h =  \frac{r^3 - 2}{13}.$$

Comment: Thank you for you answer!